# Microsoft Word - Collecting form data online

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

I have a word template file that I've set up following the directions here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010030746.aspx

That setup allows me to collect data in a Word document.  I'd like to actually have the collection element of this be online.  How can I export this so that the form side is online, but the user can generate the filled-in word document at the end of the process?